# why python raise a error ：“float argument required, not unicode”

Tags: python, string, unicode

```
for each_ID ,each_Title in zip(Id,Title):
    url="http://www.zjjsggzy.gov.cn/%E6%96%B0%E6%B5%81%E7%A8%8B/%E6%8B%9B%E6%8A%95%E6%A0%87%E4%BF%A1%E6%81%AF/jyxx_1.html?iq=x&type=%E6%8B%9B%E6%A0%87%E5%85%AC%E5%91%8A&tpid=%s&tpTitle=%s"%(each_ID,each_Title)
```

“each_ID”and “each_Title” are from website unicode parameters, but why it cause a “float”error,  %s is not a string?

Comment: You have *loads* of `%` formatters in your string. `%E` formats a float object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *loads* of `%` formatters in your string. `%E` formats a float object. You have several of those in your string, including at the start:

```
"http://www.zjjsggzy.gov.cn/%E6
#                           ^^
```

You'd need to double up *every single `%` used in a URL character escape*:

```
"http://www.zjjsggzy.gov.cn/%%E6%%96%%B0%%E6%%B5%%81%%E7%%A8%%8B/..."
```

That'd be a lot of work, you'd be better off using a different string formatting style. Use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
url = (
    "http://www.zjjsggzy.gov.cn/"
    "%E6%96%B0%E6%B5%81%E7%A8%8B/%E6%8B%9B%E6%8A%95%E6%A0%87%E4%BF%A1%E6%81%AF"
    "/jyxx_1.html?iq=x&type=%E6%8B%9B%E6%A0%87%E5%85%AC%E5%91%8A&"
    "tpid={}&tpTitle={}".format(
        each_ID, each_Title)
)
```

I broke the string up into multiple chunks to make it easier to read; the `{}` brackets delineate the placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `format` method on string. The existing `'%'` chars conflicting with your `%s` placeholders :

```
 for each_ID ,each_Title in zip(Id,Title):
  url="http://www.zjjsggzy.gov.cn/%E6%96%B0%E6%B5%81%E7%A8%8B/%E6%8B%9B%E6%8A%95%E6%A0%87%E4%BF%A1%E6%81%AF/jyxx_1.html?iq=x&type=%E6%8B%9B%E6%A0%87%E5%85%AC%E5%91%8A&tpid={}&tpTitle={}".format(each_ID, each_Title)
```